# Does SEO markup need to be on both versions of a website?

Tags: html, mobile, seo, canonical-link

Lets say I have 2 pages (1 for mobile and 1 for desktop)

Mobile URL: `http://www.example.com/mobile/`

Desktop URL: `http://www.example.com/`

And I put these kind of SEO tags in the `<head>` of the desktop version of my site:

```
      <meta name="description" content="Amazing Description"/>
      <meta property="og:type" content="Website"/>
      <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/"/>
      <meta property="og:title" content="Perfect Title"/>
      <meta property="og:description" content="Amazing Description For Social Media"/>
      <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/img/awesome.png"/>
```

And finally, I put this canonical tag in the mobile page:

```
      <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/">
```

Wouldn't that make it so that any additional tags placed in the `<head>` of the mobile site were ignored?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to put them there...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general SEO question that is not specifically about programming and is thus off-topic as mentioned by the [SEO tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info)

Comment: @JohnRPerry — Then it would still be off-topic. It would be on topic if you were asking *how* to grab them with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Google trusts your canonical link, then yes, only your desktop page would be taken into account.